# How to burn a program on an EXP5438 platform device in Contiki

Tags: contiki

I was trying to upload the hello-world program on a Texas Instruments EXP5438 experimenter board using Instant Contiki 2.7 in VMware (Ubuntu12.04). The compilation is done but when I try to upload I get this error

```
msp430flasher -n msp430x5438a -e ERASE_MAIN -w hello-world.hex -v -z [VCC] /bin/sh: 1: msp430flasher: not found
```

Then I installed  `msp430flasher` from Texas instruments. But when I try to run it i get another error:

```
can not load msp430lib.so..no such file or directory
```

Although I have the missing file in the same folder. I'm stuck with this.

Comment: What command are you using to burn it? For Telosb you just need `msp430-bsl-linux`, which is located in `tools/sky`. Just  `exp5438` and `wismote` require `msp430flasher`.

Comment: i was using exp5438.......

Comment: i was using exp5438.......my comamand was make Target=exp5438 hello- world....but i tried with your  make Target=msp430-bsl-linux hello- world....then says "platform doesn't exist"..i checked the contiki platform folder..there is not platform  for msp430-bsl-linux ...what should i do..

Comment: `msp430-bsl-linux` is not a target, but the name of the programmer script.

Comment: Try: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Do you still get the error after that?

Comment: now   MSP430Flasher is running but it is saying the following: "Evaluating triggers...done
* Checking for available FET debuggers: 
* Couldn't find any connected USB FETs!
* Powering down...done
* Disconnecting from device...done
* 
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Driver      : closed (MSP DebugStack not initialized)....."..and I stil have the error: "msp430flasher -n msp430x5438a -e ERASE_MAIN -w hello-world.hex -v -z [VCC] /bin/sh: 1: msp430flasher: not found"..is there any other way around this..to burn in TelosB..?

Comment: (1) check that you have the USB FET (the programmer device) attached and that the evaluation board is in the proper mode. Consult the manuals or ask on EE stackexchange for what you need. (2) check that you have `msp430flasher` in your PATH. If not, run `export PATH=/msp/flasher/directory:$PATH`, replacing `/msp/flasher/directory` with the name of the folder where you put `msp430flasher` binary.